# If $\varphi: A \to B$ is surjective, then is $\varphi^{**}: A^{**}\to B^{**}$ surjective?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$-algebras and consider a $*$-homomorphism $\varphi: A \to B$. Then the biduals $A^{**}$ and $B^{**}$ carry natural $C^*$-structures (coming from the enveloping von Neumann algebra) so that the map
$$\varphi^{**}: A^{**}\to B^{**}$$
is again a $*$-morphism.

If $\varphi$ is isometric (i.e. injective), it is easily verified (using general properties of adjoint maps on normed spaces) that $\varphi^{**}: A^{**}\to B^{**}$ is again isometric.

I'm now wondering if surjectivity of $\varphi$ implies surjectivity of $\varphi^{**}$.

We can't use the straightforward route: we have
$\varphi$ surjective $\implies $ $\varphi^*$ injective but this does not allow us to conclude that $\varphi^{**}$ is surjective. I'm starting to think there may be a counterexample!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map $\phi^{\ast\ast}$ is indeed surjective. First note that the image of $\phi^{\ast\ast}$ contains $B$, which is weak$^\ast$ dense in $B^{\ast\ast}$ by Goldstine's theorem. Moreover, as $\phi^{\ast\ast}$ is weak$^\ast$ continuous, its image is weak$^\ast$ closed by Proposition 1.16.2 of Sakai's *$C^\ast$-Algebras and $W^\ast$-algebras*. Thus it must equal $B^{\ast\ast}$.

Comment: Ah nice! I didn't know a W*-homomorphism has closed image!

Answer (score 4):

Generally, let $A$,$B$ be Banach spaces and $T:A\to B$ be a bounded linear operator. If $T(A)$ is norm-closed in $B$, then

1. $T$ is surjective $\Leftrightarrow T^*$ is injective.
2. $T$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow T^*$ is surjective.

Thus, $\phi$ is surjective iff $\phi^{**}$ is surjective.

Comment: Ok: $\phi$ is surjective implies $\phi^*$ is injective. But why does $\phi^*$ have closed range so that we can go further and deduce that $\phi^{**}$ is surjective.

Comment: If one of the operators $T, T^*, T^{**}$ has closed range, so do the other two.

Comment: Ok Why does $T$ have closed range imply that $T^*$ has closed range? A proof sketch is ok to me.

Comment: $(\ker{T})^{\perp}\supseteq T^{*}(B^{*})$ must be clear. On the other side, $f\in (\ker{T})^{\perp} \Leftrightarrow\ker{T}\subseteq\ker{f} \Leftrightarrow f = gT$ for some linear $g:T(A)\to\mathbb{C}$. Since $T(A)$ is closed, then $g$ is continuous, so $g$ has an extension to $B$ by Hahn-Banach theorem. Thus $f=T^{*}g\in T^{*}(B^{*})$. Consequently, $(\ker{T})^{\perp} = T^{*}(B^{*})$. Clearly $(\ker{T})^{\perp}$ is closed.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for sharing! Your solution is definitely the most elementary one!

Comment: You're welcome. A final related fact: Homomorphisms of C*-algebras always have closed ranges.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness of the post and as a small adition to MaoWao's excellent answer, I would like to include an argument for the proof that if $M,N$ are von Neumann algebras and $\phi:M\to N$ is a w$^*$-continuous $^*$-homomorphism, then $\phi(M)$ is $w^*$-closed. The proof below is in the same spirit as the one in Sakai's book.

Note that we can assume without loss of generality that $\phi$ is injective. For that, one needs to observe that $I:=\ker(\phi)$ is a $w^*$-closed ideal and consider the quotient $M/I$, which is also a von Neumann algebra$^{\text{note1}}$. Now the map $\psi:M/I\to N$ defined by $\psi(x+I)=\phi(x)$ is a well-defined, injective $*$-homomorphism that is $w^*$-continuous$^{\text{note2}}$ and $\psi(M/I)=\phi(M)$.

So assume that $\phi$ is also injective. As a $*$-homomorphism between $C^*$-algebras, $\phi$ is isometric. Let $y\in(\overline{\phi(M)}^{w^*})_{sa}$ with $\|y\|=1$. By Kaplansky's density theorem we can find a net $(x_i)\subset M$ with $\|\phi(x_i)\|\le1$ for all $i$ such that $\phi(x_i)\to y$ ultraweakly. But then $\|x_i\|=\|\phi(x_i)\|\le1$, so $(x_i)$ is a net in the closed unit ball of $M$, which is $w^*$-compact (by Banach-Alaoglu). Thus there exists a subnet $(x_{i_j})$ and some $x\in M$ with $x_{i_j}\to x$ ultraweakly. But then $\phi(x_{i_j})\to y$ and $\phi(x_{i_j})\to\phi(x)$. Uniqueness of the ultraweak limit yields $y=\phi(x)$. As $\overline{\phi(M)}^{w^*}$ is a $C^*$-algebra it is spanned by its self-adjoint elements of norm $1$ which we already proved that are included in $\phi(M)$, hence $\overline{\phi(M)}^{w^*}\subset\phi(M)$ as we wanted.

- note 1: one actually shows that if $I$ is a $w^*$-closed ideal then there exists a projection $e\in Z(M)$ such that $I=eM=eMe$ and thus the map $x+I\mapsto(1-e)x(1-e)$ gives an isomorphism $M/I\cong (1-e)M(1-e)$, which is a von Neumann algebra as a corner of $M$. Note also that since $e\in Z(M)$ we have $(1-e)x(1-e)=(1-e)x=x(1-e)$ for all $x\in M$.
- note 2: let $x_i+I\to x+I$ in $M/I$ ultraweakly. Transfer everything through the above isomorphism to $(1-e)M(1-e)$, so $(1-e)x_i(1-e)\to(1-e)x(1-e)$  ultraweakly. Apply $\phi$ which is known to be $w^*$-continuous to get $\phi(x_i(1-e))\to\phi(x(1-e))$. But $\phi(x_ie)=0=\phi(xe)$, so we have $\phi(x_i)\to\phi(x)$ ultraweakly.

Comment: Isn't this more difficult than Sakai's proof?

Comment: @Andromeda Because I'm using Kaplansky's theorem? Isn't such an argument implied in Sakai's proof when he says that the image of the unit ball is the unit ball of the range? Besides that everything else is the same but in different presentation I think

Comment: I don't know, I still have to go in detail through Sakai's proof.

Comment: @Andromeda I think my answer is basically the details to Sakai's proof but if something I use is unnecessary let me know and I will edit my post

Comment: Sure, I'll get back to you soon!

Comment: @JustDroppedIn The image of the unit ball is the unit ball of the image because the map is isometric. But one probably uses the Kaplansky to show that a *-algebra with weak* compact unit ball is a von Neumann algebra, or at least that seems like the easiest way.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be $*$-algebra and weak$^*$.

Comment: @MaoWao Yes, of course I didn't mean that Sakai uses KDT to prove this thing with the balls, I meant that this is used around the point where he mentions that (I admit I didn't phrase it very well)

Comment: @JustDroppedIn This is a pretty long proof and I don't see the need for reducing to the injective case. Why not proceed as follows? Since $M$ is a von Neumann algebra, the unit ball $M_1$ is $\sigma$-weakly closed (Banach-Alaoglu together with $M = (M_*)^*$). Hence, by $\sigma$-weak continuity, $\phi(M_1)$ is $\sigma$-weakly compact, and thus also strongly closed. By Kaplansky's density theorem, it follows that $\phi(M)$ is strongly closed, i.e. $\phi(M)$ is a VNA. I know it is essentially the same, but much shorter.

Comment: @Andromeda You're right, there's no need to pass to the isometric case. I just had a look at Sakai's argument and filled in the details when I posted this (Sakai also passes to the isometric case). Besides that, the reason that this is a long proof is that I'm including all the details. The heaviness of the machinery is essentially the same (Kaplansky's theorem)

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I think it is crucial to observe that $\pi(A)_1 = \pi(A_1)$ for a $*$-homomorphism $\pi$ (to apply Kaplansky density), and this is probably the reason why Sakai reduces to the isometric case because this fact is not very easy to prove. What do you think?